# How do i get two different images in listview row using volley

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get two different images in a single list-View row using volley but every time i'm getting same images in both image-view (network-image-view) and when i'm clicking on one image-view its hovering whole row.
I am new in Android and coding please help.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
   NetworkImageView thumbNail2 = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    thumbNail2.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    return convertView;
}
```

}

list_row

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />
            />





        <TextView
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/category_title_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />




        <TextView
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/category_title_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show some code please

Comment: I think you need this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: posted my codes ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
 thumbNail2.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
```

As you can notice you are passing same thumbnail to both the imageviews.Also you have to load two `Movie` at one position to display both images.Better use `GridView` or even better use `Recyclerview` with `GridLayoutManager`.if you want to use the listview ,do the following modifications.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    int size = movieItems.size()/2;
    return size ==0 ? size : size +1;// +1 for odd number of items like 3 or 5 or 7 ..so on.
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //And also you have handle the odd Items case.Better add extra null at the end if you have odd number of items
    if(position != 0){
        position = 2 * position;
    }
    Movie m1 = movieItems.get(position); 
    Movie m2 = movieItems.get(position+1); 
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    thumbNail2.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader); 
}
```